# "var" debugging reveals unexisting "System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection", what's going on?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, var, watch

I'm heavily struggling with the reading of C# configuration files, this is my latest failure:

I have all names of the sections in my configuration file, they are stored in a `List<string>`, called `names`. I would like to read its content, for which I do the following:

```
foreach (string section_name in names)
{
   var interface_settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(section_name);
   // do something with "interface_settings"
}
```

I have no idea what type `interface_settings` is, so I debug this piece of code, in order to see `interface_settings` in the watch-window, and indeed:
`interface_settings` is mentioned being of the type `System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection`.

I update my source code accordingly:

```
foreach (string section_name in names)
{
   System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection interface_settings = 
     ConfigurationManager.GetSection(section_name);
   // do something with "interface_settings"
}
```

This code is wrong: `System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection` does not exist!

How is it possible that the Visual Studio watch-window shows a non-existing type?

(I believe I can find some post, explaining how to read configuration sections and section groups, this question is especially concerning the apparently erroneous Visual Studio watch-window behaviour.)

**Edit**

Apparently the class `KeyValueInternalCollection` exists in file `KeyValueInternalCollection.cs`, as mentioned in [this URL](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/KeyValueInternalCollection.cs).

Comment: Did you add the namespace?  Did you add the reference to your project?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/KeyValueInternalCollection.cs,ad67eb6fd0b350d0) this is an internal class. But this class derives from `NamedValueCollection` that is public. Use this type instead. `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection interface_settings = ...` should work.#

Comment: @SebastianSchumann: I've managed to get it working, but I still have two (+1) questions: 1) how can I know that a class is an internal class? (The declaration is just `class Key...`, no `private` or other directives mentioning anything) 2) In order to know the parent class, I used your URL ("referencesource.microsoft.com"), but how can I find the parent class simply using the code? 3) This third question is a combination of both: when I find the parent class, how can I know this one is not an internal one? :-)

Comment: If there is no access modifier explicitly stated the default access modifier is used. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for more information. For classes `internal` is the default. You're using framework classes and they're documented in MSDN [`GetSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection?view=net-5.0).

Comment: `how can I know that a class is an internal class?` Why does it matter to you (in this context)?

Comment: `GetSection` is documented to return `NameValueCollection`. The actual type returned by an api might change between versions, or based on other external factors beyond your control. You shouldn't care if it actually returns a subtype, you should only care that it returns something which is a `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. Also, I agreed with Sebastian Schumann's advice about using NamedValueCollection instead.

Code:

```
foreach (string item in list)
            {
                NameValueCollection section =(NameValueCollection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection(item);

            }
```

> > how can I know that a class is an internal class?

Classes, records, and structs declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that aren't nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. **internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.**

It comes from the link [Class, record, and struct accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-record-and-struct-accessibility)

> > In order to know the parent class, I used your URL ("referencesource.microsoft.com"), but how can I find the parent class simply using the code?

You can use the reflection to get the class name.

```
 string type = interface_settings.GetType().BaseType.Name;
```

[image]

> > `This third question is a combination of both: when I find the parent class, how can I know this one is not an internal one? :-)`

Based on my test, you could search the key word in microsoft docs and you will find the access modifiter.

For example, the link [NameValueCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=net-5.0)
 has the following define:

```
public class NameValueCollection : System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase
```

We can know it is a public type.